# Testing low resolution on a high-res monitor

Tags: screen-resolution, dpi

I do all of my app development (i.e. HTML/CSS in this case) on high-resolution devices--a macbook retina display, and/or a retina-ready 21" mac monitor. However, one of our 2 products is actually installed on an extremely low-quality 640x480 monitor.

The problem is in things like fonts, gradients, shadows, etc., that look great on a monitor built after the year 2001, but look like crap (too pixelated) on our lovely pre-WW2 device monitors.

(Ok, maybe not pre-ww2, but man, they really suck).

I already have a resolution switcher that makes it easy to resize my gigantic browser down to 640x480 PIXELS, but it's still in beautiful high-res form.

(edit): I realize what i'm asking about isn't resolution but is, instead, DPI.

Does anyone know of a method/plugin/app that I can run to emulate the horrible, crappy, not-so-good resolution/dpi of our devices?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a good option:

http://www.browserstack.com/

Or maybe this could be what you need:

http://www.themobilewebdesignblog.com/2012/05/19/online-tools-emulators-for-responsive-design-testing/

Comment: Nope, after looking around more, I realize what I mean to say is that I want to reduce the DPI of the monitor while testing. I.e. the crappy monitor is probably 72dpi, while I'm using retina.

Comment: What if you use a virtual machine with this configuration? Maybe could  help.